# Stopping MySQL running inside Docker container corrupts data

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running MySQL inside a container for development. I have mapped a local volume to the container to try and persist data between restarts of the database container.

However, if I stop and then start the database container again, I get warnings "Cannot open table foo/bar from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists." and basically all of my data is inaccessible.

Comment: Can you show the `docker logs` for the container (assuming this contains the MySQL log)? What is the source/Dockerfile for the container? Which MySQL version? Are you using any non-default MySQL configuration? Does this happen every time even on a fresh local volume?

Comment: @danblack The image is mysql:5.7 with default configuration. If I delete the host data directory and recreate it entirely from scratch, mysql works normally when started, though of course there is no data.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @architjn Sadly not. The situation that necessitated this at work has passed, but I hope to be able to revisit it.

Comment: Didn't find a solution to this, but used `mysql/mysql-server` docker image instead of `mysql`. That somehow worked for me.